# Is there a command line switch to start vncserver in grayscale mode?

Tags: vnc

It is a simple question about vncserver.
Is there a command line switch to start vncserver in grayscale mode?
hours and hours I am searching at internet but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Define "gray scale"? And why do you want to do that?

Comment: for faster connection

Comment: What about the `-depth`, `-pixelformat` option and/or 2 lines `unset SESSION_MANAGER`, `exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` in `~/.vnc/xstartup`?

Comment: @quanta Other possible reason: The client is going to run on an e-ink device and the server on an Android phone. So more than 16 scales of gray are useless and it's important to conserve resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not done on the server side but on the client. UltraVNC for example can set it to "8 dark colors", "4 Grey colors" or "Black & White". Other clients probably can do it, too. The manual of your client is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Different clients have different options available.  I use TightVNC client and I know they have an 8-bit color option but RealVNC client lets you choose between 8, 64, 256, and full color options.